# How to write loop of data in the same excel sheet in Java using jlx?

Tags: java, arrays, excel

I have a code produce 10 results and I need to export these results in one column in Excel sheet. However, the code shows only the last result in the last 10th row.

The cods is shown down where I need to get R[i] in the same column under "A label record"

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.Number;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;

public class GetResults{
public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, WriteException{
  int [] R = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  WritableWorkbook wworkbook;
  wworkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
  WritableSheet wsheet = wworkbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
  Label label = new Label(0, 2, "A label record");
  wsheet.addCell(label);
  Number number = new Number(0, 3+i, R[i]);
  wsheet.addCell(number);
  wworkbook.write();
  wworkbook.close();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly creating a new worksheet and overwriting the previous file with it. As a result, only the results from the last loop iteration survives.

Move the worksheet and file creation outside of the loop. Each loop iteration should only add cells to the same, single sheet.

Proper indentation might have made this more obvious.

Comment: I have thus code in sperate class and I call it after lots of operations. For this I can not make it out the loop. Is there any idea to keep the worksheet inside the loop?

Comment: You don't want to create worksheets inside of the loop. You need to find the proper place for it before the loop. Maybe you want to pass the worksheet as a parameter that has already been created to the method that does the looping.